# Thread was being aborted when exporting to excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have a DataTable which is bound to a GridView.  I also have a button that when clicked exports the DataTable to an Excel file.  However, the following error is occuring:

ErrMsg = "Thread was being aborted."

Here is part of the code where the error is being thrown:

```
private static void Export_with_XSLT_Web(DataSet dsExport, 
                                         string[] sHeaders,
                                         string[] sFileds, 
                                         ExportFormat FormatType,
                                         string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        // Appending Headers
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;

        if(FormatType == ExportFormat.CSV)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
                                                      "attachment; 
                                                      filename=" + FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", 
                                                      "attachment; 
                                                      filename=" + FileName);
        }

        // XSLT to use for transforming this dataset.                       
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

        CreateStylesheet(writer, sHeaders, sFileds, FormatType);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument(dsExport);
        //dsExport.WriteXml("Data.xml");
        XslTransform xslTran = new XslTransform();
        xslTran.Load(new XmlTextReader(stream), null, null);

        using(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            xslTran.Transform(xmlDoc, null, sw, null);

            //Writeout the Content              
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());                
            writer.Close();
            stream.Close();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
    catch(ThreadAbortException Ex)
    {
        string ErrMsg = Ex.Message;
    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

After changing HttpContext.Current.Response.End to HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest, it now just goes to the finally block and I can't figure out what error message is being thrown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ThreadAbortException is thrown from the following line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Here's more [details](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) and a workaround.

Comment: I made the change, but now it just goes into the finally block and I can't figure out what the problem is now.

Comment: The code execution will always enter the finally block even if no exception is thrown.

Comment: If you want to handle other exceptions just add the catch(Exception ex) clause.

Answer (score 5):

I tried using `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest`. It did work but also exported the complete HTML Code of the page at the end of the downloaded file, which was undesirable.

```
Response.BuffferOutput = True;
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Then after a hell of effort, I bumped into the above code. And it works perfectly without any exception or undesirable code at the end of the downloaded file.

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/post/2270919.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Viral for ur help.It work for me.Thanks for saving my time.Instead of response.end() I wrote following 3 lines.Response.BuffferOutput = True;
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();

Answer (score 0):

The exception was caused by `Response.End`

One thing you can do is to logically trap the exception message...

this method will not affect the data but it will only trap the exception...

```
Try

    .........(codes here)
    Response.End

Catch ex as Message

    If Not ex.Message = "Thread was being aborted." Then
         Response.write(ex.message)
    End If

End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the different story here, I am using **telerik** controls and NONE helped me, eventually I came to know that I had to just wrap my markup in **telerik:RadAjaxPanel**, below is the code snippet to disable ajax on RequestStart Client side event handler.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" 
    ClientEvents-OnRequestStart="AjaxRequestStart">
```

and then in my user control, I added just one more function as depicted below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AjaxRequestStart(target, arguments) {
        arguments.set_enableAjax(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its simple, you can try:

`Response.Close();` in place of `Response.End();`